# Materializecss - slider WITH materialboxed (lightbox)?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, materialize

Using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/), is there any way to **combine** the [slider component](http://materializecss.com/media.html#slider) **with** [material box](http://materializecss.com/media.html#materialbox)?

I've tried this:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img class="materialboxed" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1" > 
    </li>
    . . .
  <ul>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer your question without any code or a link or jsfiddle but did you initialize materialbox?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
});
```